# What should be posted on Ask Ubuntu's Google+ page?

Tags: discussion, community, google+

We've set up **[+Ask Ubuntu](https://plus.google.com/b/107921963368679288414/)**! Now we need your feedback about what to post on it.

Would you like top questions? What criteria? Anything else?

Or can you think of a better way to gather and review posts for the AU page?

Comment: Does anyone know if the G+ API extends to pages yet? 'Cause I'd love to write something that auto posts popular questions / answers every so often similar to the Twitter feed.

Comment: I think, and no offense to the Twitter feed (which is great at finding bad questions :P), the Google+ page should be a *little* smarter than automation

Comment: I have to agree with @MarcoCeppi on this one. The Google+ page needs to be smarter at "finding" AWESOME questions.

Comment: Oh... isn't there *something* on the page we can automate?

Comment: @jrg: By "smarter" you mean not automated? ...or just smarter?

Comment: @GeorgeEdison Yes.... to both. Automated smartness would be awesome.

Answer (score 5):

How to Answer and How to Ask from the FAQ! Also a link to the newsletter.

Comment: Yeah - those would be static links?

Comment: how would I link to the newsletter? The page on se.com only has all of them simultaneously.

Comment: @StefanoPalazzo I would just post the "ad" they have on the page here for the newsletter on G+

Answer (score 3):

Bounties ofc, so pll can be updated of nice rep bounties for fancy questions.

Comment: Yes, but we also want to notify people of questions with good answers :)

Comment: Rather than a constant "please answer this qusetion, please"